# Can I prevent IDEs from auto-wrapping attributes via TSLint or tsconfig?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ide, phpstorm, tslint

When we use PhpStorm to auto reformat code, it wraps at 120 characters. I know I can manually set this in PhpStorm's editor settings, but I have to tell each person on the team to do that on every one of their machines in order to accomplish this. And we don't all use PhpStorm either.

Is there a standard, best practice way to set this via `tslint.json` or `tsconfig.app.json` so that IDE's wont autoformat to wrapped attributes?

For instance, I can set `"max-line-length": [ false ]` in my tslint.json file and it does impact whether I get warnings but doesn't change the behavior of auto-formatters. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you consider create `.editorconfig` file with settings like max-line-length. Will be more easy for new developers in project to config IDE however you will have to duplicate some logic. https://editorconfig.org/

Comment: PhpStorm supports `.editorconfig` files. Since next 2019.2 that plugin will be bundled by default; right now (2019.1 and older) you need to install it manually. IDE reads settings from that file and overrides appropriate stuff from own Code Style. [max_line_length](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#max_line_length) is what you need. This, of course, does not affect TSLint and stuff .. so you would need to configure them as well (which you do already, as I understand).

Comment: P.S. From 2019.2 you will be able to export (and therefore share) whole Code Style via .editorconfig file (uses domain-specific properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TSLint [max-line-length](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/max-line-length/) rule supports setting the limit in `tslint.json`, like:

```
"max-line-length": [
      true,
      60
    ]
```

If you import code style preferences from TSLint using **Apply TSLint Code Style Rules** action

[image]

the **Hard wrap at** value in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Wrapping and Braces** will be set accordingly:

[image]